How to update ML model that was preloaded in Gunicorn
Below is a simple example of serving ML-model with FastAPI.
I want to run my gunicorn server like this: gunicorn --workers=4 --preload app.main:app  --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --timeout=60
My desire is to download the model in the main process (use --preload option) and run the function that periodically runs the download of a newer version of a model.
(pseudocode)
while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(interval)
            mlflow_service.download_model_files()

I don't understand how to implement the periodical model-download and update that new model in memory so that ALL WORKERS can see changes and use the updated model for inference. I don't want to download/update the model 1 time for each worker, it requires way too many resources. I just want to run this "from one shared place" so that all workers can see the change and run the new model. I realize that can be an isolated service like Torchserve, but I need to do it this way.
I also know I can use Redis as a cache where I can store the latest model version and trough that workers can know what version to use, but again, I don't want to download/update the model in every worker. Is this even possible?
EDIT: I found something interesting, but don't know if it is really useful: https://github.com/fastapi/fastapi/issues/4257#issuecomment-988704329
import asyncio
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

app = FastAPI()
sbertmodel = None


def create_model():
    global sbertmodel
    sbertmodel = SentenceTransformer('multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1')


# if you try to run all predicts concurrently, it will result in CPU trashing.
pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1, initializer=create_model)


def model_predict():
    ts = time.time()
    vector = sbertmodel.encode('How big is London')
    return vector


async def vector_search(vector):
    # simulate I/O call (e.g. Vector Similarity Search using a VectorDB)
    await asyncio.sleep(0.005)


@app.get("/")
async def entrypoint(request: Request):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    ts = time.time()
    # worker should be initialized outside endpoint to avoid cold start
    vector = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, model_predict)
    print(f"Model  : {int((time.time() - ts) * 1000)}ms")
    ts = time.time()
    await vector_search(vector)
    print(f"io task: {int((time.time() - ts) * 1000)}ms")
    return "ok"

